# Formula to get comma-delimited list of unique values from table column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, list

I have a table in Excel 2016:

[image]

```
ID  TIME_PERIOD
--  ---------------
1   FORECAST
2   HISTORY
3   BEYOND FORECAST
4   HISTORY
5   BEYOND FORECAST
6   BEYOND FORECAST
7   FORECAST
8   FORECAST
9   HISTORY
10  BEYOND FORECAST
```

When printing the table as a PDF/report, I plan to *exclude* the TIME_PERIOD column from the report print area, due to limited space in the report.

As an alternative to showing the entire column in the report, I want to get a **list of the column's unique values as a comma-delimited list.**

---

I would need the list's formula to honor any filters that are applied to the field. For example, if I were to filter to only show FORECAST, then the unique list would honor that filter.

[image]

---

**Question:**

Is there a formula I can use to get a comma-delimited list of unique values from the table column?

The table's data source is ever-changing (rows get added and deleted upon refresh). So the formula would need to dynamically reference the entire column -- not be hardcoded to a specific range.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want, you may find it easier to create your report using Power Query (`Get & Transform` in Excel 2016) or even Power BI

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your task correctly, try the following formula:

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(INDEX(B7:INDEX(B7:B1000,COUNTA(B7:B1000),1),,1),FALSE,FALSE))

In Excel 2016 try this:

=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(B7:INDEX(B7:B1000,COUNTA(B7:B1000),1),,1),SMALL(IF(MATCH(INDEX(B7:INDEX(B7:B1000,COUNTA(B7:B1000),1),,1),INDEX(B7:INDEX(B7:B1000,COUNTA(B7:B1000),1),,1),0)=ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(ROWS(INDEX(B7:INDEX(B7:B1000,COUNTA(B7:B1000),1),,1))-0))),MATCH(INDEX(B7:INDEX(B7:B1000,COUNTA(B7:B1000),1),,1),INDEX(B7:INDEX(B7:B1000,COUNTA(B7:B1000),1),,1),0),""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(ROWS(INDEX(B7:INDEX(B7:B1000,COUNTA(B7:B1000),1),,1))-0))))),"#"))&", "),"#,","")

Comment: Not sure `TEXTJOIN` & `UNIQUE` are available in 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is named *Table1*:

`=MID(CONCAT(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX(Table1[TIME_PERIOD],1),ROW(Table1[TIME_PERIOD])-MIN(ROW(Table1[TIME_PERIOD])),)),MATCH(Table1[TIME_PERIOD],Table1[TIME_PERIOD],0)),ROW(Table1[TIME_PERIOD])-MIN(ROW(Table1[TIME_PERIOD]))+1),", "&Table1[TIME_PERIOD],"")),3,2^15)`

which will most likely require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` for your version of Excel.